# Adding additional chapters in table of contents using the listed template

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, overleaf, thesis

I am using [this](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template) template for my thesis, which provides a table of contents that includes only the list of figures and list of tables before the main chapters.

Ideally, I would also like to add the table of contents itself, the acknowledgements, the declaration and the dedication pages which I have partially achieved as seen on the attached image.

[image: Table of contents]

However, I experience the following problem when using the command

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter_name}
```

where chapter_name = Abstract, Declaration, etc.

to generate these listings:

While the page numbers depicted are correct, when I click on them they redirect me one or two pages earlier than the displayed number, depending whether there is a blink page between the chapters or not.

Also, how can I add the table of contents listed as well?

EDIT 1:
The `\phantomsection%` command slightly fixes the issue but still redirects me to the blank page that is between the chapters.

EDIT 2:
I managed to add the table of contents too but still having the same problem of redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question:

```
\cleardoublepage
```

must come before the

```
\phantomsection
```

command, and then the redirection points to the correct page.

Example in the correct order:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter_name}
```